# Getting SQL error while reading the data

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products",con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader["ProductName"].ToString() == "dsd")
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Products", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ListView1.DataSource = ds;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

reader.Close();
```

Error :

> Already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

I am getting error on this line `da.fill(ds)`. And I used two commands one `SqlCommand` to read the record and second `SqlDataAdapter` to show record.

Comment: `reader.Read()` start reading the data and `da.Fill(ds);` starts reading again. But what are you trying to achieve with this code (it makes no sense)

Comment: Oh year, that's the same query twice. So if he has 100 products, hell read the entire product table 1+100 times.

Comment: This code makes no sense.  Try explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need two connection objects. One for your open data reader and a second to use with the SqlDataAdapter.

(Or you can use [MARS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109(v=sql.90).aspx), but really it is far better to just open a second connection.)

Comment: It is still the right answer to the question about the error message. Even if his example code is nonsensical, the next person with the same question may legitimately need to run a query inside a loop.

Comment: It is only the right answer if you want to actually execute the 2 statements concurrently. In most cases the proper answer is to close the initial reader.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to bind a listview control with all the products by name "dsd".

If this is correct, you can change the SQL query like this:
    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = 'dsd'

You can read the response from the DataReader and prepare the List to bind to your listview control. I don't think you need DataSet to bind to listview control.